# How to exclude gitignore files from cx_Freeze distribution

Tags: python, git, cx-freeze

I’m including some data directories in my project with the `include_files` option to `build_exe`. However, these directories contain .gitignore files, which I don’t want to be included in the distribution.

Is there any way to use a pattern to exclude any files that would otherwise be included? I have looked trough cx_Freeze documentation, but none of the options seem to do the trick.

Comment: If you're using a setup.py script, can you just generate a list of all the files in the directory besides the `.gitignore`, and pass that in?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Function `glob.glob` even excludes files starting with a dot by default. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution (as suggested by [Thomas K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/434217/thomas-k)) is to use [glob](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/glob.html) module to generate an excplicit list of files to be included.

```
from glob import glob
sql_files = glob('../sql/*/*')  # No files in ../sql/ root
doc_files = glob('../doc/*') + glob('../doc/*/*')
buildOptions = dict(include_files=list(zip(sql_files, sql_files))\
                                  + list(zip(doc_files, doc_files)))
```